# How to load an XML file from a remote site

Tags: php, xml

There is site , *shop.test.com.au*  (not a real name)

when ever i tried to take the site  through 
*http://shop.test.com.au/* , it will change to *shop.test.com.au* in the browser

They providing an xml page link on that site

I need to access that xml from my php page

Following is my code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('shop.test.com.au/1.xml');
```

Then it will return an error "**failed to open stream: No such file or directory**", may be it is checking in my local machine.So i changed the code to

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->load('http://shop.test.com.au/1.xml');
```

Then i gets an error "**failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!**"

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best would be to use CURL, make sure you have CURL installed and then use this

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://shop.test.com.au/1.xml");

$xml = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

And there you go - $xml should be having the data you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$f = file_get_contents("http://shop.test.com.au/1.xml");
```

Then, at the very least, that should give you the HTTP status code of the error.

Once you get the XML (hopefully by resolving the error), use:

```
$doc->loadXML($f);
```

You may find that the site blocks requests with no User Agent specified (I know my site does), so you might need to use cURL or Socket functions to pass a User Agent.

Comment: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Comment: See, whenever I've had such things, it always follows "HTTP request failed" with the status code, such as "HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"